# Pass PHP array onto Vue component using props

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, vue.js

- Building a Laravel app with a few Vue components
- Want to pass a PHP array onto a Vue component using props

Here's an example of such PHP array:

`["Foo" => 100, "Bar" => 50]`

Great. Here's my attempt at passing them onto the Chart component:

`<Chart points="{!! json_encode($points) !!}"></Chart>`

This looks fine, but the strings (Foo and Bar) inside the `$points` array get encapsulated with " (double quotes) when using `json_encode()`. This means that whenever the 1st string appears in the array, the browser thinks that the " is meant to close the `points` attribute.

Here's what you get to see in the browser:

`<Chart points="{">Foo":100,"Bar":50}"</Chart>`

How do I go about this? I have been struggling with this for hours now, and I can't wrap my head around it.

- Can't use " (double quotes) since the browser interprets it as the closing quote for an attribute and messes up the HTML
- Can't use ' (single quotes) since that's invalid JSON (and json_encode doesn't support it)

Comment: `["Foo": 100, "Bar": 50]` is not a PHP array.

Comment: @DarraghEnright good spot, fixed it.

Comment: Could you try `:points='{!! json_encode($points) !!}'`? The alternative would be to set the array into your Vue / component `data`, eg `data: { points: {!! json_encode($points) !!} }` and use `:points="points"`

Comment: `points='{!! json_encode($points) !!}'` works, however I'm uncertain if this is considered invalid or bad HTML?

Comment: @D.vanDrunen it would probably fail if any of the values contained a single-quote

Comment: Gotcha, but does it screw with HTML validation or doesn't it matter if you use ' or "?

Comment: There is no difference between single `'` or double `"` quotes in html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<Chart points='{!! json_encode($points) !!}'></Chart>
```

Just use singular quotes.

Comment: Why the fudge is it single quotes?  
I've just struggled for hours battling this problem with double quotes, and this is actually the solution that worked.   But.... I really don't understand what is happening here as they should be the same between single and double!

Comment: This is because in JSON structures, keys and values are surrounded by double-quotes already, so using double-quotes to wrap the returned JSON structure will obliterate the rendered HTML with a malformed JSON blob kind of mixing the returned JSON and the element's attribute.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, I'm not sure why was it accepted. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/48980512/623373

Comment: Hands up if you're here in 2022

Answer (score 9):

Although reading previous answers this took me a while to get working. So, here's what works for me with Laravel 5.5 and VueJs 2.5:

1. Convert your PHP array to a JSON serialized string.

   For PHP arrays see [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
   For Eloquent collections see the Eloquent method [toJson](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-tojson).
   For further reference we call this new JSON string `$arrayAsJSON`.
2. In your view (or Blade template):

   ```
   <some-vue-component :componentProperty="{{ $arrayAsJSON }}"></some-vue-component>
   ```
3. The Vue Component:

   ```
   <template></template>

   <script>
     export default {

       props: ['componentProperty'],

       mounted() {
           console.log('some-vue-component mounted.');
           console.log(this.componentProperty)
       },
     }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Can use formal way:

```
<Chart points='<?php echo json_encode($points); ?>'></Chart>
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Laravel 5.5 you can use the @json directive.

`<Chart points=@json($points)></Chart>`

Comment: It works as in the accepted answer but still needs single quotes around it in my case

Comment: You might be right. Might have mixed html and javascript tag.